# Missing dependency for method at parameter at index Rest WebService Java

Tags: java, rest, query-string

In my Restful web service, a method takes 4 parameters. String String String and Object. All other methods are working fine except this method with Object as parameter. 
I am using Query param. I am getting the following exception when trying to run it on server.

```
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public org.Result org.tempuri.Rest.Client2.update(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object) at parameter at index 3
SEVERE: Method, public org.Result org.tempuri.Rest.Client2.update(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object), annotated with POST of resource, class org.tempuri.Rest.Client2, is not recognized as valid resource method.
```

Code :

```
public Result update(@QueryParam("fname")String fname,   @QueryParam("lname")String lname, @QueryParam("key")String key, @QueryParam("value")Object value){

            Result r = null;

                r = Update.update(fname, lname, key, value);

            return r;
        }
```

Comment: i guess it is expecting 4th argument to be string only. mention string and verify the result.

Comment: please also check the import package.

Comment: If I change it to String, it is working fine. But I want it to be a Object as value of that key can either be String or int. Import package is fine as all other methods are using the same package.

Comment: do a string argument then parse to a int if needed. anyways you have to typecast to Int/String. avoid usage of Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4th argument passed should be String not Object to avoid exception.

Comment: Now I have similar method which takes Striing[] keys, String[] values as parameters. And it is giving the same error. Can you please help me with that

Comment: i.e., instead of String key and String value in the above method, it takes String[] keys and String[] values and updates all the values.

Comment: try it out with List<String> . link http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/jax-rs-queryparam-example/